# Selenium C# 4.0 release says you can hide the command prompt - how do you actually do it?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm updating to version 2.40 and was looking at the change log. http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/dotnet/CHANGELOG

It says "Now provide an option to hide command prompt window for driver service
   executables (IEDriverServer.exe, chromedriver.exe, etc.) in .NET bindings."

I can't find what setting to use to make this happen. How do I do it?

Comment: How do I overload my edge driver() with DriverDirectory, DriverService and Options. Or how do I apply all three to my driver? So I'm doing this: ```
EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
options.AddArgument("headless"); EdgeDriverService myDriverService = new EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
myDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true; EdgeDriver edgeDriver = new EdgeDriver(Setup.DirectoryPath, options); //Want to apply myDriverService
//in here how would I apply a myDriverService to the method, there's no overload for Driver Directory, options and Driver Service, only Driver Di

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can hide command prompt window now in Selenium 2.40.0. I was writing a blog article about this earlier, which you might want to have a look [here](http://yizeng.me/2014/03/05/hide-command-prompt-window-in-selenium-webdriver-net-binding/).

Please note that hiding command prompt window is not recommended.

ChromeDriver

```
var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

var driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, new ChromeOptions());
```

InternetExplorerDriver

```
var driverService = InternetExplorerDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(driverService, new InternetExplorerOptions());
```

PhantomJSDriver

```
var driverService = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

var driver = new PhantomJSDriver(driverService);
```

Comment: Interesting that it is an option, even though it is not suggested. Do you know an acceptable use case for this?

Comment: @Aligned: If someone is using Selenium to develop an application that runs on client's computer. So it is a good idea to hide command window. Otherwise for testing purposes, I can't think of any.

Comment: @Aligned It's an option because enough people who use the .NET bindings asked for it, even though the maintainer of the .NET bindings believes it to be a mistake to hide the window. If, for some reason, your WebDriver code fails, and incorrectly doesn't call the `.Quit` method, with the command prompt window showing, it's blatantly obvious there's an extra process running. With the command prompt window hidden, it's not obvious.

Comment: @YiZeng Is there any way to achieve this in `Python` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
ChromeDriverService chromeservice = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
   chromeservice.HideCommandPromptWindow = true; //hide console window
   ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeservice);

   FirefoxDriverService firefoxservice = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
   firefoxservice.HideCommandPromptWindow = true; //hide console window
   FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxservice);
```

Several other [Selenium](https://www.brainbeast.best/faq-about-selenium-webdriver-on-c-sharp-with-examples/) tools